# How to install grass addons when offline?

Tags: grass-gis, add-ons

Can anyone tell me how can I install GRASS (v.7) addons on a windows PC when offline?

I manually downloaded the files from http://svn.osgeo.org/grass/grass-addons/grass7/ and copied:
- the .py file to ...\GRASS GIS 7.0.svn\scripts 
- the .html file to ...\GRASS GIS 7.0.svn\docs\html

But the GRASS GUI does not recognize them.

Comment: http://wingrass.fsv.cvut.cz/grass70/addons/ place them in the installed location apps\grass\grass-7\etc\python\grass\lib